What is the terminal command in Linux to convert docx to odt?
Another topic suggested using the following command to batch convert docx files to odt:
libreoffice --headless --convert-to odt *.docx
I discovered that it actually only changes the file extension (basically re-saves the file but with the .odt extension).
This was confirmed When I edited a 'converted' file, and tried to save it, and I got the "Save as..." dialog, because I needed to save it as .odt.
Is there a command that will actually convert files to odt?
